# How can I access the name or value of an li element?

Tags: jquery

I have an li element that looks like this:

```
<ol id="selectbox">
    <li class="boxes" name="bears">bees</li>
    <li class="boxes" name="cakes">candles</li>
    <li class="boxes" name="wine">beer</li>
    <li class="boxes" name="spoon">fork</li>
    <li class="boxes" name="bench">chair</li>
    <li class="boxes" name="matches">fire</li>
    <li class="boxes" name="kindling">wood</li>
</ol>
```

When I click it, I would like to get the name 'bears', OR the text 'bees' into a variable (It would be helpful to know how to do both).  How can I do this with jQuery selectors?
I've tried many things such as

```
var $radios = $('input[name="mybuttons"]');
$('#selectbox li').click(function(){
  var $btn = $(this).addClass('active');
  var idx = $btn.index();    
  var name = $('li['+idx+']').name();
});
```

and

```
var name = $('#li.active').name()
```

and

```
var name = $radios.eq(idx).prop('name')
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` in the click event context as it corresponds to the element is clicked.

```
var name = $(this).attr('name');  // bears 

var val = $(this).text();       // bees
```

**Code**

```
$('#selectbox li').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var $btn = $this.addClass('active');
  var name = $this.attr('name');
  var txt = $this.text();
  console.log("Name Attribute - " + name + " :: Text - "+ txt); 
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/E8GrB/)**

Also it is better to use **data attributes** for custom attributes so that the Document will be validated and compliant with the standard practices.

So

```
<li class="boxes" name="bears">bees</li>
```

Should look like

```
<li class="boxes" data-name="bears">bees</li>
```

to acces it you can use either `.attr()` or the `.data()` methods

```
var name = $this.attr('data-name');
var name = $this.data('name');
```

Answer (score 2):

use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the text

```
$(this).text()
```

and [.attr('name')](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the name

```
$(this).attr('name')
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/VaVm6/)

Answer (score 1):

It would be as simple as this:

```
$('#myOL li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var text = $(this).text(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,

```
 $('#selectbox .boxes')
```

returns an array of all elements with class boxes within #selectbox
By using jQuery to make your life easier you could do this

```
$('#selectbox .boxes').click(function(){
  var tmp_name = $(this).attr('name');
  alert(tmp_name);
  alert($(this).text()); // bees
  alert($(this).html()); // bees
  // changes the attribute name of this li element which has class boxes and has been clicked.
  $(this).attr('name','Hello world!'); 
  // changes the inner html of this li element which has class boxes and has been clicked.
  $(this).html('Hello world!');

})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: great.  thanks a ton.  i didn't realize i could access the array that easily.  is this preferred practice?  i'm wondering if this is somehow better than ('#myOL li') if that class (boxes) doesn't show up outside of such a context...

Comment: Well it is good to specify where to look for those .boxes so that you dont scan the entire document. $('#selectbox .boxes') gets the element with id selectbox and looks for elements with the class boxes inside it.It's faster.Just make sure you only have 1 element with id selectbox.